# Visualizing a correspondence analysis over time

Tags: data-visualization, factor-analysis, correspondence-analysis

I have two contingency tables of frequency data examining the same set of variables but at two different time points.

I can make two separate before and after correspondence analysis plots but would anyone know if there's a method to combine these into one graph - say with some small line, arc or graphic to show any movement of the attributes (or just plot the attribute before and after points in different colours?